# Sitecore Form Fallback

Tags: sitecore-forms, language-fallback

Is there any out of the box feature or  way to Implement fallback for Sitecore Forms .
I create a sitecore Form in a language and add it to a page ,currently if i open the page in other language the field names in Form disappears.
How to enable the fallback for Sitecore Forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have item language fallback enabled and setup for your solution? Otherwise that would be a first step.

But: item language fallback only works for items that have the item language checkbox ticked. So you need to have those on for the items in your forms.

You could accomplish this by changing the standard values of the relevant templates (the templates related to Forms) or you could also create a rule for the Item Saved event that sets the value for that field to 1 if the item is.. (tbd - could be for all items in your forms folder).

Comment: Yes, updating the standard values of the relevant templates worked. Thank you!!